# Create area line graph that colors in-between series?

Tags: graph, highcharts

I am trying to create a new Area Line Graph that colors the space in-between the two lines, but for some reason I cannot accomplish this. The default behavior is to color the area from the series to the x-axis. Is there a way that you can only color in the space between the two series instead?

I am trying to mimic the behavior, but with HighCharts, here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/185729594/report_chart_created_vs_resolved_report.png?version=3&modificationDate=1354064895573&api=v2

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "Range" chart.  Highcharts does not have this ability directly, but with a little work, you can get close:  http://www.highcharts.com/studies/range.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the area range chart type: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange